# How can I use Terraform workspace to switch between aws and localstack?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to use `Terraform` workspace to manage two environment, one for aws, the other is for `localstack`. Below is the configuration file of Terraform. I don't want the `endpoints` and `skip_xxx` properties on `aws` workspace. How can I implement that logic? The only way I can think of is to create multiple folders for different environments, such as `aws`, `openstack` and `shared`. But I'd like to find a solution on `workspace` since it is build-in feature with Terraform for different envs.

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "ap-southeast-2"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true

  endpoints {
       lambda = "http://localhost:4574"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: I am using `v0.12.4`

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform workspaces feature is for storing multiple states in a single location and switching between them. If you wish to store states in different locations (different S3 buckets, or in your case one not using S3 at all) then [the workspaces feature is not appropriate](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces).

Instead, you can use multiple configuration roots and factor the shared configuration out into one or more child modules that both configurations share. Your separate root modules can then represent *all* of the differences between these targets, including the different backend configurations.

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "ap-southeast-2"

  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true

  endpoints {
    lambda = "http://localhost:4574"
  }
}

module "shared_something" {
  source = "./modules/shared-something"

  # Configuration for this module that makes sense for localstack
}
```

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "ap-southeast-2"
}

module "shared_something" {
  source = "./modules/shared-something"

  # Configuration for this module that makes sense for real AWS
}
```

If your configuration is relatively simple then having just a single shared module with everything in it may be sufficient, but for more complex situations you may need to use [module composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html) to decompose the system and better support any configuration variations that are needed between AWS and localstack.

Note that the Terraform AWS provider supports non-AWS implementations only on a best-effort basis and may not behave correctly if localstack is not 100% behavior-compatible with AWS. If you are using any third-party modules then they may make assumptions that do not hold for localstack.

Comment: How do I place these two different provider files? How does terraform choose one not the other based on the workspace? I think all configuration files are visible for all workspaces. Right?

Comment: Each configuration would be in a separate directory